# Wimpy powerset function

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Define the 'wimpy powerset function' $\mathcal{W} : \mathrm{Set} \rightarrow \mathrm{Set}$ by writing $$\mathcal{W}(B) = \{X \in \mathcal{P}(B) : |X| < |B|\}.$$

A few preliminary observations.

1. If $B$ is finite, then $|\mathcal{W}(B)| + 1 = |\mathcal{P}(B)|.$
2. If $B$ is countable (e.g. take $B=\mathbb{N}$), then $|\mathcal{W}(B)| = |B|.$

What else is known about $\mathcal{W}$? In particular:

- What can we say about $\mathcal{W}(\aleph_1)$ and $\mathcal{W}(\beth_1)$?
- Do there exist sets $B$ such that $|\mathcal{W}(B)| = |\mathcal{P}(B)|$?

Comment: Nice name, nice question.

Comment: Just be patient, sooner or later Asaf Karagila will answer your question with or without assuming ZFC ;-)

Comment: A nice example without choice: Consider, say, Solovay's model, where the size $\mathfrak c$ of the reals is a successor of $\aleph_0$, but $\aleph_1\not\le\mathfrak c$. It is a theorem of Tarski that for any set $X$, the collection $\mathsf{WO}(X)$ of well-orderable subsets of $X$ has size strictly larger than the size of $X$. In this case, this means that $|\mathcal W(\mathbb R)|>\mathfrak c$. But one can check that in this case $|\mathcal P(\mathbb R)|>|\mathcal W(\mathbb R)|$.

Comment: Another remark without choice: A Dedekind finite set is a set $X$ such that $|Y|<|X|$ for any proper subset $Y$ of $X$. It is consistent without choice that there are infinite Dedekind finite sets. If $X$ is infinite and Dedekind finite, then either $\mathcal P(X)$ of $\mathcal P^2(X)$ is Dedekind infinite (both cases are consistent). If $Y$ is $X$ or $\mathcal P(X)$, whichever is Dedekind finite and has Dedekind infinite power set, then $\mathcal W(Y)$ has the same size as $\mathcal P(Y)$. On the other hand, if $\mathcal P(X)$ is Dedekind finite, then $|\mathcal W(X)|<|\mathcal P(X)|$.

Comment: It is fun to come up with names, but this already has two notations: $[\kappa]^{<\kappa},\mathcal P_\kappa(\kappa)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're assuming ZFC, right?

$|\mathcal W(\omega_1)|=\beth_1$.

$\beth_1\le|\mathcal W(\beth_1)|\le\beth_2$;
if $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, then $|\mathcal W(\beth_1)|=\beth_1$, but
if $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ and $2^{\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_2}=\aleph_3$, then $|\mathcal W(\beth_1)|=\beth_2$.

$|\mathcal W(\beth_{\omega})|=|\mathcal P(\beth_{\omega})|=\beth_{\omega+1}$.

Comment: 1. Yes, assume ZFC. 2. If you could spell out a little how you came to these conclusions, that would be great!!

Comment: @user18921 What you need to verify is that if $\kappa$, $\lambda$ are infinite, with $\kappa\ge\lambda$, then $[\kappa]^\lambda$, the collection of subsets of $\kappa$ of size exactly $\lambda$, has size exactly $\kappa^\lambda$.

Comment: @user18921: Pursuing Andres’s comment: if $\kappa\ge\lambda$, then $|\kappa\times\lambda|=\kappa$, and it’s easy to find $\kappa^\lambda$ distinct subsets of $\kappa\times\lambda$, each of power $\lambda$, so $\left|[\kappa]^\lambda\right|\ge\kappa^\lambda$. The opposite inequality is even easier.

Comment: @Brian: In fact $^\lambda\kappa\subseteq[\lambda\times\kappa]^\lambda$.

Comment: @Asaf: Sure, but I wanted to make it absolutely clear that we could easily pick $\kappa^\lambda$ distinct **subsets**.

Comment: I guess I missed something. Why the rollback?

Comment: Don't you need $\sf SCH$ (at least for $\beth_\omega$) for that last one?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Count subsets of size $\omega$ of the form $\{x_n\mid n<\omega\}$ where $x_0<\beth_0$, $x_1\in[\beth_0,\beth_1)$, etc. There are $\prod_n\beth_n$ such sets. This is $2^{\sum\beth_n}=\beth_{\omega+1}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila (Last night I kept reading $\beth_\alpha$ as $\aleph_\alpha$ for some reason, and thought the same. I even started to write a version of the comment above. Only at the end I noticed the right symbol.)

Comment: @Andres: ...and thus proving beyond any shadow of a doubt, that I should grade that last paper (from the pile of "sheet no. 3") tomorrow morning, and go to bed. Thanks!

Comment: @AsafKaragila OK, homework then: Can we always find $X$ with $|\mathcal W(X)|=|\mathcal P(X)|$ in the absence of choice?

Comment: @user14111 Why unnecessary? The counting for $\beth_\omega$ becomes a standard thing after a while, but not terribly intuitive if one has not encountered anything like it before.

Comment: @Andres: Thanks. You have guaranteed that I won't grade papers tomorrow. I'll be hanged and flayed for the eventual delay of the grades... But that's a good question, for tomorrow.

Comment: @AsafKaragila :-)

Comment: @user14111, your edit got my +1 vote, and I perhaps I should have said 'thank you' more explicitly, but it is my understanding that 'thank you' comments are generally discouraged around here unless they contain some actual mathematical content. And since there were other comments with more interesting things to say, I thought it better to just hold my peace. Sorry if I made a misjudgement; I can see how, from your point of you, my silence may have appeared rude. That was not my intention.